# Joining two tables and computing sum of one column, however retain row from left table if no matches in right

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

`original`

| SIM_NUM | SECID | FV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 1 | TB20240521 | 38,000 |
| 1 | TB20250621 | 40,000 |
| 1 | TB20270621 | 15,000 |
| 2 | TB20230421 | 34,000 |
| 2 | TB20240521 | 38,000 |
| 2 | TB20250621 | 40,000 |
| 2 | TB20300821 | 50,000 |

`sims`

| SIM_NUM | SECID | FV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TB20230421 | 3,000 |
| 1 | TB20240521 | 4,000 |
| 1 | TB20250621 | 5,000 |
| 2 | TB20230421 | 2,000 |
| 2 | TB20240521 | 3,000 |
| 2 | TB20250621 | 1,000 |

I'd like to join the two tables on `SIM_NUM` and `SECID`, summing the `FV` column. But for `SIM_NUM`s and `SECID`s in `original` that do not appear in `sims`, they should also appear in the joint table.

The desired outcome is:

| SIM_NUM | SECID | SUM_FV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TB20230421 | 37,000 |
| 1 | TB20240521 | 42,000 |
| 1 | TB20250621 | 45,000 |
| 1 | TB20270621 | 15,000 |
| 2 | TB20230421 | 36,000 |
| 2 | TB20240521 | 41,000 |
| 2 | TB20250621 | 43,000 |
| 2 | TB20300821 | 50,000 |

Query to create the sample tables:

```
CREATE TABLE original (
    SIM_NUM int,
    SECID varchar(10),
    FV int
)
INSERT INTO original (SIM_NUM, SECID, FV)
VALUES

(1,'TB20230421', 34000),
(1,'TB20240521', 38000),
(1,'TB20250621', 40000),
(1,'TB20270621', 15000),
(2,'TB20230421', 34000),
(2,'TB20240521', 38000),
(2,'TB20250621', 40000),
(2,'TB20300821', 50000)

CREATE TABLE sims(
    SIM_NUM int,
    SECID varchar(10),
    FV int
)
INSERT INTO sims (SIM_NUM, SECID, FV)
VALUES

(1,'TB20230421', 3000),
(1,'TB20240521', 4000),
(1,'TB20250621', 5000),
(2,'TB20230421', 2000),
(2,'TB20240521', 3000),
(2,'TB20250621', 1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A left outer join and [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) function will do what you expect.
see the following code as example:

```
select
  o.SIM_NUM,
  o.SECID,
  o.FV + COALESCE(s.FV,0) as FV
from
   original o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   sims s
ON
  o.SIM_NUM = S.SIM_NUM
AND
  O.SECID = S.SECID
```

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eee8b3/3)

[image]

IF we want to use full outer join, then the query can be re-written as below:

```
select
  COALESCE(o.SIM_NUM, s.SIM_NUM) as SIM_NUM,
  COALESCE(o.SECID, s.SECID) as SECID,
  COALESCE(o.FV,0) + COALESCE(s.FV,0) as FV
from
   original o
FULL OUTER JOIN
   sims s
ON
  o.SIM_NUM = S.SIM_NUM
AND
  O.SECID = S.SECID
```

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b6ea8/2)
[image]

Comment: Thanks, what about if I also wanted to retain rows in `sims` which do not appear in `original`? I tried `full outer join` but got `NULL`s. For example add one row in `sims`: `(2,'TB20400121', 10000)` which should be in the final result.

Comment: Hi @Renegade_rm56,  I have updated my answer to include a version with full outer join, it works for the new row you just added.

Answer (score 0):

you can join both tables and have so the possibility to use all columns.

The COALESCE will take the first value that is not 0

I choose FULL OUTER JOIN as it is not clear if both tables have the same sim_num and so you would loose some rows

```
SELECT
  COALESCE (o.SIM_NUM,s.SIM_NUM) as SIM_NUM
  ,  COALESCE (o.SECID,s.SECID) as SECID, COALESCE(o.FV,0) + COALESCE(s.FV,0) as FV
FROM 
original o FULL OUTER JOIN sims s ON s.SIM_NUM = o.SIM_NUM AND  s.SECID =  o.SECID
```

| SIM_NUM | SECID | FV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TB20230421 | 37000 |
| 1 | TB20240521 | 42000 |
| 1 | TB20250621 | 45000 |
| 1 | TB20270621 | 15000 |
| 2 | TB20230421 | 36000 |
| 2 | TB20240521 | 41000 |
| 2 | TB20250621 | 41000 |
| 2 | TB20300821 | 50000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vWotdO8R)

Answer (score 0):

Left join your tables and then ISNULL on your sims.FV. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ng7wRUVH)

```
SELECT o.SIM_NUM
     , o.SECID
     , o.FV + ISNULL(s.FV,0) AS SUM_FV
  FROM original o
  LEFT JOIN sims s ON o.SIM_NUM = s.SIM_NUM 
                  AND o.SECID = s.SECID
```